# Keep selected value in collection_select as active after submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Dear All,
**View**

```
<form align="center" name="gm" action="">
 <label for="col1"><b>Name: </b></label> 
 <%= collection_select(@table, "gm", @pop1, "col1", "col1", :prompt => true) %>
 <%= submit_tag value="Proceed-->"%>  
 <form name="sp" action="">
  <label for="col2"><b>Class: </b></label>
  <%= collection_select(@table, "sp", @pop2, "col2", "col2", :prompt => true) %><br><br>
   <%= submit_tag value="Submit"%>  
</form>
```

Here, these are relational collection_select. I need to populate the second collection_select once first collection_select was selected. But, once "Proceed" submit was processed, params[gm] was disabled. So I am unable to process "Submit" tag with both params[gm] and params[sp] for @table. Any idea to keep selected value in collection_select to remain after click "Proceed".

Comment: I think, observe_field will help in this regard. But, I dont know to implement that one.... please anyone help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I use

```
<%= collection_select(@table, "gm", @pop1, "col1", "col2", :prompt => true, :selected=> params[:gm]) %>
```

It works!